# Changing the order in for-loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a matrix (with the size of A and B; suppose 100x100) and want to fill in with smaller matrix (or block) with the size of a and b (suppose 12x12).

As it is clear, the loop starts from "j" and then goes to the next row. Actually I want to use the same loop, by adding another variable to impose that it first complete the columns. Any idea that how I should define this new variable in the following loop to control the completion direction.

```
M = zeros(100,100);

for j = 1:12:100-12+1
    for i = 1:12:100-12+1
        block = rand(12,12);
        M(i:i+11, j:j+11) = block;
        imagesc(M); axis equal tight xy
        pause(.1)
    end;
end;
```

Comment: What? Kindly rephrase this to be sensical. And why is this tagged c++?

Comment: I removed C++. I just wanted to know the ideas of C++ programmers!

Comment: @Sam: Please stop tagging your question which are totally unrelated to c++ with `c++` to get more attention. You already did so in previous questions!

Comment: I think it is a general question that all of the programmers can answer. It does not matter matlab or C++.

Comment: @Sam: There is no reason to tag any general question with `c++`. This would make the tag totally useless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do

```
M = zeros(100,100);

for j = 1:12:100-12+1
    for i = 1:12:100-12+1
        block = rand(12,12);
        M(i:i+11, j:j+11) = block;
        imagesc(M); axis equal tight xy
        pause(.1)
    end;
end;
```

Now you will iterate over the i's first.

Incidentally, I recommend not using `i` and `j` as loop variables - they shadow the built in `sqrt(-1)` imaginary number...

**update** based on your comment, it seems you want to leave the order of `i` and `j` in the outer loop, and add "another parameter" to change the direction.  The following code does all that. Is this what you are after?

```
M = zeros(100,100);
rowFirst = true; % set to false for "column first"
for i = 1:12:100-12+1
    for j = 1:12:100-12+1
        block = rand(12,12);

        if rowFirst
          M((0:11) + i, (0:11) + j) = block;
        else
          M((0:11) + j, (0:11) + i) = block;
        end

        imagesc(M); axis equal tight xy
        pause(.1)

    end
end
```

**update 2** and now "even for non square matrix" (not tested, late at night):

```
M = zeros(100, 120);
rowFirst = true;
sz = size(M);
blockSize = 12;
v = 1:blockSize;
nrc = floor(sz / blockSize);
if rowFirst
  nrc = reverse(nrc);
end
for ii = blockSize * (0:nrc(1)-1)
  for jj = blockSize * (0:nrc(2)-1)
    block = rand(blockSize*[1 1]);
    if ~rowFirst
      block = block';
    end if
    M(v + ii, v+jj) = block;
    if rowFirst
      imagesc(M);
    else
      imagesc(M');
    end
    axis equal tight xy
    pause(0.1)
  end
end
```

**LAST TIME** if you insist that the outer loop iterates over `j` and the inner loop over `i`, yet that in some instances `j` is the "faster moving" variable, you can do the following.

```
P = 120;
Q = 180;
M = zeros(P, Q); % not a square matrix
rowFirst = true; % a switch you can flip
blockSize = 15;  % size of block
sz = floor(size(M)/blockSize); % number of iterations in j, i
nr = sz(1); nc = sz(2);
vv = 1:blockSize;

for jj = 0: (nc-1)
  for ii = 0: (nr-1) 
    if(rowFirst)
      kk = ii * blockSize;
      ll = jj * blockSize;
    else
      nn = jj * nr + ii;
      ll = mod(nn, nc);
      kk = floor(nn / nc);
      %ll = (nn - kk * nc);
          fprintf(1, 'ii, jj, nn = [%d, %d, %d]: [kk, ll] = %d, %d\n', ii, jj, nn, kk, ll)

      ll = ll * blockSize; kk = kk * blockSize;
     % mod(nn, P);
    end
    M(kk+vv, ll+vv) = rand(blockSize*[1 1]);
    imagesc(M); 
    axis tight equal xy;
    pause(0.1);
 end
end
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to change the i and j in the loop! I just want to add another parameter to change the direction. So, I want to first start with j and then i.

Comment: Actually it does not work when I change 100 (in i loop) to 120 !! It just enlarge the matrix which I don't want to change the its size. any idea?

Comment: Are you asking "how do I modify this so it works for non square matrix"?

Comment: I tried to write an updated solution, see if this works for you. The "I don't want to change the outer loop" requirement now becomes very restrictive so you end up doing a lot of crazy stuff in the inner loop. It would be so much cleaner to have just one `if` statement around the nested loops...

Comment: what is "reverse"? (I am using matlab)

Comment: Try `fliplr` - it reverses the vector left to right. Basically you would get the same with `size(M')`. Which is really what we are doing here. As I said, you end up doing crazy stuff to stick with the "one outer loop" requirement...

Comment: It again enlarge the matrix in another dimension and the output size does not match with size of M. I also don't want to flip any matrix, otherwise, I would simply rotate the M.

Comment: @sam - see if my latest version does the job for you. I still think it's a strange way to do this - frankly you might as well have a single counter instead of `ii` and `jj`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and all of your efforts to help me :)